# How to select pandas DataFrame rows where a column has non-Nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to express in Pandas the equivalent of the following SQL

```
    select * from df where col_a is not null
```

Comment: `df[df['col_a'].notnull()]`?

Comment: Yes @JohnGalt, that did it.  But looking at the question that you indicated was a duplicate had an answer that did not work, at least as I understood the answer.

Comment: @verisimilidude The equivalent of `df[df['col_a'].notnull()]`  is `df.dropna(subset=['col_a'])`  But EdChum also offered an alternative there which is same as John Galt's suggestion: `nms[nms.name.notnull()]`

Comment: Thank you @ayhan, `dropna` is what I need.  I wish I could give you a +1 and a checkmark for your concise discussion of equivalents.  I am trying to show R <-> pandas equivalency and na.omit in R is best paired with dropna.